# get polygon name when marker place on polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hi i have i one question for polygon and marker, i have more then 50 polygon in map with its id now i want when i search address and put marker on map then i want to get that polygon id where marker is place

this is my code for drop polygon in map

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: objArray,
            strokeColor: 'green',
            id:zoneid,
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            draggable: false,
            editable: false
        });
        polyline.setMap(map);
```

i use this map for dispaly marker on polygone 
[image]
when i put marker on polygon then i want to get that polygon id 
if you have any example or proper solution then please send me

Answer (score 1):

Use the geometry library.  Firstly specify that as a parameter when loading in the JS:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
```

Then when you create a marker, use its coordinates and check if it's in each of your polygons.  You probably want to put each polygon into an array that you can loop over.

```
var markerCoords = marker.getPosition();

for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(markerCoords, polygons[i])) {
        var id = polygons[i].id;
        break;
    }
}
```

See:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation

Comment: plz downgrade my number -1 to 0

Comment: @Trusharnarodia please don't direct that comment to me.  Someone rating your question -1 has got nothing to do with my answer.